# How to fix the Boot screen being stuck with “Failed to start Gnome Display Manager”

Tags: boot, gnome, 22.10

My computer is stuck at a boot screen, with the line says “Failed to start Gnome Display Manager”. I was moving images from folder to folder, and then I had an error saying it’s not responding, now goes the gnome. How do I fix this?

My computer is Ubuntu 22.10

Comment: Which files were you moving? I'm assuming you moved some files that Gnome requires. Also, when you say it's stuck at the "boot screen", do you mean it's not reaching the login screen? Does it respond to `Alt`+`Ctrl`+`F3` to go into TTY mode when that error is displayed? Are you able to start in safe mode or command-line mode?

Comment: Yes, It’s not reaching to the login screen. I was actually moving images, and yes it did go into a tty mode. I’m not enabled to start in safe mode or command-line.

Comment: It wasn’t what gnome requires, only screenshots that I took pictures of.